# I have Start Date Time And End Date Time How To Show End Sale in iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, timer, swift4

I have start date and end date strings, how to show the end Sale timer like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE2TS.png) image?

"Start-date":"Dec 18, 2019 05:15:00 +0000","End-date":"Dec 27, 2019 11:15:39 +0000"

Please help!

Comment: where you've attached the sample image? do you have date as string? Can you post the code what you tried so far?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE2TS.png

Comment: You need to explore `Calendar` and `DateComponent` class

Comment: in above Start-date , End-date i'm geting from back end i need to show timer like attached image

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582967/how-to-make-a-countdown-to-date-swift) out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the date string to Date first, then you can use timer to update the timer labels based on start and end date.

Use `Calendar` and `dateComponents` method to find the day, hour, minute and second differences between dates and then set the value on day, hour, minute and second labels as like you attached image.

Example implementation:

```
var timer:Timer?
var endDate:Date?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    startTimer()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    stopTimer()
}

func startTimer(){

    let endDateStr = "Dec 27, 2019 11:15:39 +0000"

    let dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = dateFormat

    endDate = dateFormater.date(from: endDateStr)
    //stop timer if it's already running
    stopTimer()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateSaleTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer(){

    if timer != nil{

        timer!.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}

func updateSaleTime(){

    guard let d2 = endDate else {
        stopTimer()//Check if the date-format is correct for end date string.
        return
    }

    let cal = Calendar.current

    let components = cal.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: d2)
    let day = components.day!
    let hour = components.hour!
    let minute = components.minute!
    let second = components.second!

    //set the value on day, hour, minute and second labels as like you attached image.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate the difference between the startDate and the endDate it will alway be the same . Instead you can calculate the difference to  endDate from the current date.
Check the following implementation.

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {

        let endDate : Date? = {
            // To create Date from date string received from server 
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
            // Convert to desired Timezone
            return dateFormatter.date(from: "Dec 18, 2019 06:30:39 +0000")
        }()

        var timer : Timer?

        private func starCountDown() {
           timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

        private func stopCountDown() {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }

        @objc func updateTime() {

             guard let endDate = endDate else {
                stopCountDown()
                return
            }

            let countdown = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: endDate)
            let days = countdown.day!
            let hours = countdown.hour!
            let minutes = countdown.minute!
            let seconds = countdown.second!

            if days <= 0 && hours <= 0 && minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0  {
                stopCountDown()
                print("Offer Expired")
                return
            }

            print(String(format: "%02d Days , %02d Hours, %02d Mins, %02d Sec", days, hours, minutes, seconds))
            // set values as per your requirement
        }

        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            stopCountDown()
        }


        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
           starCountDown()
        }

    }
```